# Find the largest drop between two numbers in an array. What is the time complexity of this code?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, time-complexity

I have an array full of numbers. I need to find the maximum difference between 2 numbers but the biggest number is before the smallest number in the array.

`public static int maximalDrop(int[] a)`
For example:

for the array `5, 21, 3, 27, 12, 24, 7, 6, 4` the result will be `23 (27 - 4)`

for the array `5, 21, 3, 22, 12, 7, 26, 14` the result will be `18 (21 - 3)`

I think I write it in time complexity `O(N)` is my code ok? What is that time complexity of my code? Here is the method that I write:

```java
public static int maximalDrop(int[] a) {
    int i = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int result = -1;
    int k = a.length - 1;
    boolean finishCheckLoop = false;
    while (k > i) {
        if (a[i] < a[i + 1] || finishCheckLoop == true) {
            i++;
            finishCheckLoop = false;
        } else if (a[i] >= a[k] || a[i] <= a[k]) {
            if (a[k] < 0)
                temp = Math.abs(a[k]) + a[i];
            else if (a[k] > 0)
                temp = a[i] - a[k];
            result = Math.max(temp, result);
            k--;
        }
        if (i == k) {
            k = a.length - 1;
            finishCheckLoop = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think your code gives correct result. for the array `5, 21, 3, 27, 12, 24, 7, 6, 4` the maximal drop should be `24 (27-3)`. Unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: iterate over array using a for loop and find index of maximum number. Once you have it do `int maxDrop = a[maxIndex] - a[maxIndex-1];` The time complexity will be O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be `O(N)`, but it is quite complex for the task.

A simpler (and faster) version:

```
public static int maximalDrop(int[] a) {
  int maxDrop = 0;
  int drop = 0;
  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  int cur;
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    cur = a[i];
    if (cur > max) {
      max = cur;
    }
    drop = max - cur;
    if (drop > maxDrop) {
      maxDrop = drop;
    }
  }
  return maxDrop;
}
```

Disclaimer, I don't really write java, so I'm not sure if the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is correct.

Comment: wow guys thank you very much it opens my mind to new technics  and I need to use paper and pen before writing solotion thanks:)

Comment: @kurkle `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is just fine, don't worry!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code has a time complexity of `O(N)`, but it's not readable and was probably hard to write.

Almost all of us have this bad tendency to start coding before we know how to solve the problem.
The code presented here seems like a product of this technique.

To improve the code, we should pick up a pen and paper and think simple. Note that we need to return the maximal drop from left to right so there are quite a few cases

Let's keep `high`, `low` and `maximalDrop` variables:

- The current number is a new low:

  1. `low` = current number.
  2. Update the `maximalDrop` if necessary.
- The current number is a new high - the previous low is irrelevant.
- Else - do nothing.

Now it's easy to code:

```
public static int maximalDrop(int[] a) {
    if (a.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    int h = a[0], l = a[0];
    int maxDrop = -1;

    for (int curr : a) {
        if (curr < l) {
            l = curr;
            maxDrop = Math.max(h - l, maxDrop);
        } else if (curr > h) {
            h = curr;
            l = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }

    return maxDrop;
}
```

Output examples:

```
System.out.println(maximalDrop(new int[]{5, 21, 3, 27, 12, 24, 7, 6, 4})); // 23
System.out.println(maximalDrop(new int[]{5, 21, 3, 22, 12, 7, 26, 14}));  // 18 
System.out.println(maximalDrop(new int[]{5, 6}));  // -1
```